# How to open a text editor in Windows via calling some variable like edit or vi from the commandline

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I need to use Windows in my current job, and I've mostly been a Ubuntu and Mac user. How can I set up variable shortcuts to be used in the command prompt?

For example, I want [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) or some other text editor like TextPad to open when I type the command `vi` or `edit` on the command prompt.

I tried `doskey vi=textpad`.

But that just allows me to open the program, not the file I was trying to open. For example, if I type `textpad filename.txt`, it opens the expected file for editing. But when I set an alias of `vi=textpad`, it just opens TextPad as a program forgetting the reference to the actual file I wanted to edit.

Comment: What you need is to create aliases:

http://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line

Comment: yea but the that just allows me to open the program not the file I was trying to open. For example, if I type `textpad filename.txt`, it opens the expected file for editing. But when I set an alias of `vi=textpad`, it just opens textpad as a program forgetting the reference to actual file I wanted to edit.

Comment: I made an edit to the question to include my findings so far with trying aliases

Comment: @TazMan here is how to do exactly that in PowerShell: http://superuser.com/questions/355817/how-to-make-powershell-alias-to-execute-a-file

Comment: And this is how you would do that in cmd as explained in the linked answer: doskey vi=textpad $*

Answer (score 4):

You have the tag `powershell` in your question, so assuming that is the command prompt you are normally reading you need to use a `Set-Alias` cmdlet or define a function:

```
Set-Alias vi textpad
```

should get you started.

To avoid entering this every time you start a new command prompt you should insert the command into your profile. Try `textpad $profile` to edit the startup profile, but be aware that you may need to create the parent folders first as they don't exist by default. The command `new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force` will create the profile file and any parent folders.

Here's a tested example using my preferred editor:

```
PS C:\> set-alias vi 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eps13\bin\sendeps.exe'
PS C:\> vi c:\temp\t.txt
```

`set-alias` won't let you include any parameters; it just aliases the command itself. If you want to pass any other arguments to your editor use a function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Write some short batch scripts and store them in a folder that is on the path, such as `c:\windows` or `c:\windows\system32` but it's neater to create a dedicated folder for your scripts and utilities and add that folder to the PATH in control panel, system, advanced, environment variables.

Use this as a template and then you can also use `vi "text file name.txt"` or `vi file*.txt`

```
::vi.bat
@echo off
start "" "c:\folder\executable name.exe" %*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit text files within PowerShell as follows:

```
bash -c "nano index.html"
```

The command above open the index.html file using nano editor in PowerShell

Alternatively, you can open it with vim using the following command

```
bash -c "vi index.html"
```